# Casting vtable class to void pointer (C++)

Tags: c++

I am writing library that is supposed to initialize some data and return void pointer. Pointer is then used in C code.
Inside library I want to use C++ class to initialize this data.

```
void *init()
{
    return new MyData();
}
void fini(void *d)
{
    MyData *m = reinterpret_cast<MyData *>(d);
    delete d;
}
```

This works while MyData is simple class without virtual methods. But now I want MyData to be an implementation of abstract class.

```
class Base // No virtual things
{
   int val;
};
class A : public Base // Abstract class
{
    virtual int x() = 0;
};
class B : public A // Implementation
{
    int x() {return val;}
};
```

If I then cast this class to void*, first 4 bytes of data will not reflect "val" variable of base class. Because of vtable maybe? Fine, I understood that this is wrong way to cast. Any suggestions? Something like

```
return static_cast<Base *>(new MyData);
```

seems to work but i also need to reconstruct MyData from void * and delete it properly. C program will only use values from Base part of MyData.

Here is alternative

```
void *init()
{
    return new MyData();
}
void fini(void *d)
{
    delete reinterpret_cast<MyData *>(d);
}
void *getbase(void *d)
{
    MyData *m = reinterpret_cast<MyData *>(d);
    return static_cast<Base *>(m);
}
```

but i'd like to avoid third function. Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: "seems to work but i also need to reconstruct MyData from void * and delete it properly." Is it a problem, or why don't you choose this solution?

Comment: Can I delete it this way? delete static_cast<MyData *>(reinterpret_cast<Base *>(d));

Comment: Sure. `delete static_cast<A*>(static_cast<Base *>(d));`

Comment: Thanks. Going to check...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Comment: Just use virtual destructors and you're ok.

Comment: Thanks. It is more about casting. I was afraid to loose vtable or something when casting to simple Base.

Comment: @SimonKraemer : No he isn't.  The problem is that he has a void *, and he need to delete that - but he needs the full object to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete static_cast<A*>(static_cast<Base *>(d));
```

Worked in all tests. Thanks to geza.